# How do I handle unit testing an after insert trigger on Chatter posts that contain attachments?

Tags: trigger, unit-test

**TL;DR - I need to finish a unit test for my trigger and don't know how. I'm stuck. See code below.**

I have this trigger that works when I test it manually, but I am having trouble writing a unit test that actually initiates the trigger. Therefore I can't get more than about 30% coverage.

The gist of the trigger is this: when a chatter post is made in a chatter group called "Deal Committee", and there is an attachment to the chatter post, then that attachment (ContentDocument) is added to a Library called "Deal Committee Attachments". If the document is already in the Library, then it updates a field called Date_Added_to_Library__c to NOW()

Here's the trigger. The comments are mainly for my benefit. :)
(I am aware I have two queries inside a FOR loop and that's not good, and I would like to rewrite it when I have a chance, but for now I'm on a tight schedule and it's what I have and it works. Suggestions around fixing that are welcome but mainly I want to get this unit test written.)

**Trigger**

```
trigger dealCommitteeChatterAttachment on FeedItem (after insert) {

    //find the ID of the chatter group called "Deal Committee" and then find the id of the Library called "Deal Committee Attachments
    id cgid = [SELECT id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Deal Committee'].id;
    id lid  = [SELECT id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Deal Committee Attachments'].id;
    Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();

    for (FeedItem f : Trigger.new) {

        //whenever a new chatter post is made, first check if it's being posted in the Deal Committee group AND check if it has any attachments
        if (f.ParentId == Id.valueOf(cgid) && f.Type == 'ContentPost' ) {

            //If either answer (from above) is false, then do nothing
            //If both answers (from above) are true, then do a check to find out if the attached document has already been shared in the Deal Committee Attachments library
            **ContentVersion[] contentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :f.RelatedRecordId];            
            integer duplicatecheck     = [SELECT count() from ContentWorkspaceDoc WHERE ContentDocumentID = :contentId[0].ContentDocumentId];**

                //If it has been shared to the library already, don't add it again, but simply update the "Date Added to Library" field to NOW()
                **if( duplicatecheck > 0 ) {
                   ContentVersion cv = contentId[0];
                   cv.Date_Added_to_Library__c = System.now();
                   update cv;
                }**

                //If it has never been added to the library, then add it           
                else if( duplicatecheck == 0 ) { 

                    **ContentWorkspaceDoc c = new ContentWorkspaceDoc();            
                    c.ContentDocumentID   = contentId[0].ContentDocumentId;
                    c.ContentWorkspaceID  = Id.valueOf(lid);                       
                    insert c;
                }
        }** 

    //Otherwise do nothing
    else  {}
    }
}
```

Here's my unit test as it is now. It says it covers the trigger at 31%. As far as my knowledge goes, it should be covering everything. Clearly I'm wrong but I don't understand what I'm missing. I think it's not even initiating the trigger to create the ContentWorkspaceDoc at all, which means none of the other code is going to run, and i don't know why.

**Unit Test**

```
@isTest
private class dealCommitteeChatterAttachment_test {

    @isTest(SeeAllData=True) static void addToLibraryTest() {
        List<CollaborationGroup> cgId = [SELECT id FROM CollaborationGroup WHERE Name = 'Deal Committee' LIMIT 1];
        List<ContentWorkspace> lid = [SELECT id FROM ContentWorkspace WHERE Name = 'Deal Committee Attachments' LIMIT 1];

        ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion();
        cv.ContentURL = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com</a>';
        cv.Title ='Google.com'; 
        insert cv;

        ContentVersion datecheck1 = [SELECT Date_Added_to_Library__c,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE id = :cv.id];
        System.Debug(datecheck1.ContentDocumentId);

        FeedItem fi1 = new FeedItem();
        fi1.ParentId = cgid[0].id;
        fi1.body     = 'test';
        fi1.Type     = 'ContentPost';
        insert fi1; 

        FeedAttachment fa1 = new FeedAttachment();
        fa1.FeedEntityId = fi1.id;
        fa1.type         = 'Content';
        fa1.RecordId     = cv.id;
        insert fa1;

        FeedItem fi2 = new FeedItem();
        fi2.ParentId = cgid[0].id;
        fi2.body     = 'test 2';
        fi2.Type     = 'ContentPost';
        insert fi2;

        FeedAttachment fa2 = new FeedAttachment();
        fa2.FeedEntityId = fi2.id;
        fa2.type         = 'Content';
        fa2.RecordId     = cv.id;
        insert fa2;        

        ContentVersion datecheck2 = [SELECT Date_Added_to_Library__c FROM ContentVersion WHERE id = :cv.id];
        System.Debug(datecheck1.Date_Added_to_Library__c);
        System.Debug(datecheck2.Date_Added_to_Library__c);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used tools like Developer Console or Mavensmate to find out which lines are covered and which are not?

Comment: I do not think these two queries will return anything `ContentVersion[] contentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :f.RelatedRecordId];            
            integer duplicatecheck     = [SELECT count() from ContentWorkspaceDoc WHERE ContentDocumentID = :contentId[0].ContentDocumentId];` bu difficult to tell. Easier you you know what lines are not covered

Comment: Yes, at this point I think I know what's happening but don't know how to fix it. 

You are right. That first query is not returning anything. I believe the reason is because the trigger is firing IMMEDIATELY as soon as the FeedItem is inserted in the test, but BEFORE the FeedAttachment is inserted. Therefore my query is basically saying "give me the ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion where id = null", because FeedItem.RelatedRecordId is null.

I have tried updating my trigger to fire after insert of FeedAttachment but that is apparently not allowed.

Comment: So now I need to find a way to write a unit test that inserts a FeedItem WITH a FeedAttachment at the same time, so that there will be a value in FeedItem.RelatedRecordId. How do you do that?